# Cannot assign value of type '((T) -> Void)?' to type '((T) -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift

```
import Foundation

class ParentClass<T>
{
    var _success : ((T)->Void)?
}


extension ParentClass
{
    func success<T>(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass where T : Codable
    {
        self._success = success
        return self
    }
}
```

I am trying to store generic closure in to variable for later use but compiler throwing an error."Cannot assign value of type '((T) -> Void)?' to type '((T) -> Void)?'"

Answer (score 5):

You've introduced a local generic variable `T`, which is shadowing the (unrelated) generic variable `T` of `ParentClass`.

```
import Foundation

class ParentClass<T>
{
    var _success : ((T)->Void)?
}


extension ParentClass where T: Codable
{
    func success(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass
    {
        self._success = success
        return self
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't really make sense that your success function is an instance method. It should be an initializer, or a static method instead.

Comment: Like the existing Result? And how does this answer help with the Codable part?

Comment: @matt Result isn't super prevalent yet, so there's still a need to shuttle around 2 independent success/faliure closures. "And how does this answer help with the Codable part?" I probably should have mentioned that the constant needs to be on the extension declaration, I'll edit that in now

Comment: @Alexander Cool Thanks! Any other way to relate two generic variable here in my question?

Comment: @BevinPatel Just omit the second one entirely, as I showed. You don't need it.

Comment: Could you show an example of how the CompletionHandler enum would be used? For example, if I wanted to pass a completion handler to `downloadImage`, it seems to me that I would have to pass each case separately, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, an enum is totally the wrong choice. I need to stop stackoverflowing before my first coffee of the day.